# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'localtime'

Tags: python-3.x

I usually have sandbox where I try snippets of code out.

When I run the following code in my sandbox it works as expected

```
 tuple_current_time = time.localtime(time.time())

    print("tuple_current_time = ", tuple_current_time)
```

But when I run it in the module I am developing I get the error

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'localtime'

```
if not (sched_time) == "TIME":
    print("Its not equal", sched_time)
    #print ("Variable Type : ",  type (tuple_current_time))
    #Create a tuple of current time


    tuple_current_time = time.localtime(time.time())

    print("tuple_current_time = ", tuple_current_time)

    tuple_website = newtuple=(tuple_current_time[0], tuple_current_time[1],            tuple_current_time[2], sched_hour, sched_min, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    print("tuple_website = ", tuple_website)

    if tuple_website > tuple_current_time:
        #print("Website tuple is newer than current time tuple")
    else:
        #print("Current time tuple is newer than website time tuple")
```

Please can anybody advise what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You obviously have `time` defined as a string and not as the imported module. Now it's not possible to tell you where is the error because you don't show enough code for that (the matching `import` statement and all subsequent places where you use `time`).

Comment: Thanks - I am struggling to understand and find out the difference between 'import time' and 'from time import time'

Comment: Thanks your comment about the matching import statements was an amazing clue - and I worked out the problem from there - many thanks